# Contributions Import ... Not

Tags: civicontribute, import, data-import

Using Drupal 9.3.22 and CiviCRM 5.52.3

Importing a csv file with 44 contributions and a header row into an existing system.

The csv file is uploaded, we set the mappings, and then the next page says that there are the right number of rows, but 0 contributions, and it has no next button.

No errors are displayed, either on screen or in any of the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I "fixed" this, or at least, it now works, after trying a lot of different strategies. The last thing I did before it started working was to run

```
cv api System.utf8conversion
```